# Is it random what prisoner you unlock?

Tags: battleblock-theater

I have played BattleBlock Theater and I want to know how the prisoners are unlocked. When I spend 10 Gems it unlocks a prisoner. I want to know if it is a random from all of the prisoners, or if there is a pattern. For example, if I begin all again will the prisoners be unlocked in the same order, or is there a random order that you unlock the prisoners in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's random. The [Battleblock Theater Wikia](http://battleblocktheater.wikia.com/wiki/BattleBlock_Theater) agrees with me:

> Gemstones are later used to free (unlock) the over 300 prisoners. The **unlock process is random**, however, with each turn-in.

Comment: oh ok thanks :) . So if it is random we can have two same prisoners ?

Comment: You mean if you can get one you already have? No, because if you have all of one shape, you can't buy that shape anymore.